# spring-security-core Grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, grails-2.5

Using **spring-security-core:2.0-RC5 plugin** , and added

```
@Secured('ROLE_USER')
```

to the Human controller , when i go to this URL

> http://localhost:8080/MyApp/human/index

it suppose to forward me to the login page  as this action is protected, but instead of that it gives me `this page can't be displayed` as shown below . how this could be fixed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it don't work without square brackets but  works as below

> @Secured(['ROLE_USER'])

or as

> @Secured(value=["hasRole('ROLE_USER')"])

From `@Secured(['ROLE_USER'])` it is apparent that it take list of roles and not a single role string. To give role as string you should be using value attribute from Secured annotation and then call hasRole('your_role').

Hope it helps!

**Edit**

Additionally check for spring security settings. Below are mines:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com..User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.groupAuthorityNameField = 'authorities'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useRoleGroups = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl="/home/index"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules  = [
        '/':                ['permitAll'],
        '/error':           ['permitAll'],
        '/index':           ['permitAll'],
        '/index.gsp':       ['permitAll'],
        '/shutdown':        ['permitAll'],
        '/assets/**':       ['permitAll'],
        '/**/js/**':        ['permitAll'],
        '/**/css/**':       ['permitAll'],
        '/fonts/**':        ['permitAll'],
        '/**/images/**':    ['permitAll'],
        '/**/favicon.ico':  ['permitAll'],
        '/login/**':        ['permitAll'],
        '/logout/**':       ['permitAll'],
        '/dbconsole/**':    ['ROLE_ADMIN'],

]
```

Hope these helps!

Comment: changed it as you suggested but still getting the same result.

Comment: Seems there is problem with other spring security settings.Did you check you spring security configurations. Are these proper?

Comment: what are the spring security configurations i need to check ?

Comment: Yes! Let me edit and give you my spring configuration. May be these could help!

Comment: i have some of the configs you posted and i didn't change them since i installed the plugin : `grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.security.Users'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.security.UsersRoles'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.security.Roles'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/login/auth' `

Answer (score 0):

when reviewing my Config file i found :

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
```

when i commented it ,everything worked fine.

Comment: if my answer looks good to you. Please accept it. Did you try with square brackets or with square brackets?